# SSH: Effects of no-pty login option in authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, security, openssh, ssh-tunnel, authorized-keys

I'm confused by the behavior of `restrict` or `no-pty` login options prepended to a key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

For a given key I was intending to prevent **any** interaction **except** for starting an SSH tunnel to a particular local port:

```
restrict,permitopen="localhost:80" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA[...]3c7rmJT5/ tunnel@a.example.com
```

The actual effect is that identifying with the corresponding private key I can create a tunnel, but apparently **also execute arbitrary commands**:

```
tunnel@a $ ssh -i tunnel_rsa user@b.example.com

PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-64-generic x86_64)

[...]

You have new mail.

ls .ssh/
authorized_keys
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
known_hosts
```

Note `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0` message at the beginning of the session (which suggest that the login option takes some effect) and `ls .ssh/` command with it's output.

There is no prompt, but it's not what I was intending to do. Can someone please shed some light on this? Also, what is the preferred method to restrict given key to only creating a tunnel?

**update**

with `restrict` the tunnel is not really working:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

or using HTTPie:

```
$ http :8080
http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

with following output from `ssh -L ...` command:

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

It does work with `no-pty` option instead of `restricted`, but the original problem remains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research and experimentation this combination of options seem to do the trick:

```
command="",restrict,port-forwarding,permitopen="localhost:80"
```

Let me go through each of them individually:

- `command=""`

  disallows any command to be executed using this key
- `restrict`

  Disable all options, such as TTY allocation, port forwarding, agent forwarding, user-rc, and X11 forwarding all at once.
- `port-forwarding`

  Enables TCP port forwarding, but see below.
- `permitopen="localhost:80"`

  Limits TCP port forwarding to local port `80`. That's the **only** thing this key should allow.

I've been able to figure this out mainly by reading [Client Configuration Files chapter of OpenSSH WikiBook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Client_Configuration_Files), so the majority of credit goes to it's authors (Lars Noodén et al.). Missing part was `port-forwarding` - without it forwarding is forbidden even though `permitopen` would suggest otherwise.

Comment: thanks for great hint to use `restrict` instead of `no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty`